# Rails: List all the items from a table to drop-down list using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Rails.
I use devise for authentication in my Rails 5.0.1 project.

```
# Here is my Helper Module

module CategoriesHelper
 def categories_for_select
   Category.all.collect { |m| [m.name] }
 end
end
```

#### in _form.html.erb page

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :category_name %>
<%= f.select(:category_name, categories_for_select, :prompt => 'Select') %>
<%= link_to 'Create New Category', new_category_path %>
```

How can I list all the items from the **Category table** to a drop-down list that is associated with the current_user.

**UPDATE:**
Schema

```
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "name"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.integer  "user_id"
end
```

Comment: Have you actually set up a relation between your user model and categories?

Comment: Yes, It currently displays all the categories posted by other users.

Comment: Don't you think that is a pretty important part of the question? Any possible answer depends on how you have setup that association.

Comment: category contains the user_id of the created user.

Comment: `current_user.categories` ??!! Please supply all necessary information in the question.

Comment: Is there a way to sort it from the "view page" i.e, from the select tag.

Comment: Have deleted my answer (`current_user.categories.pluck(:name)`) as can't seem to get any coherence out of OP.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. What is "my view page" ?(Is it a `show`, a `new`, an `update`, ... ? What resource is it modifying?) Why is there a form (with the declaration not shown), then a link to **`new`**? ... What do you mean by "sort it" -- do you mean *filter* it (which we've already answered), or *order* it alphabetically/whatever? What relevance, if any, is the fact that you're using `Devise` ... Or just the fact that you have a `current_user` method?

Comment: @DamienRoche undelete , since with the OP's edit it seems to be correct.

Comment: Sorry.. I mean 'filter'..  I solved the issue with damien's answer.. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `User` `has_many` `categories`, you can simply do:

```
current_user.categories.pluck(:name)
```